# Ubuntu shell script - Scanning the drive for archives: ERROR: No more files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I have installed the package

> p7zip-full

for ubuntu and I am running the following shell script named 7z and placed within the same directory as the dataset zipped files

```
#!bin/sh
mkdir ./min6dB
mkdir ./0dB
mkdir ./6dB
7z -omin6dB -y x ./-6_dB_valve.zip
7z -omin6dB -y x ./-6_dB_pump.zip
```

The dataset folder looks as in the image

[image]

and I get the error below

```
Scanning the drive for archives:

ERROR: No more files
```

although this certain file exists within my directory.
How can I resolve the issue?

I use Ubuntu app for Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Your shebang should looks like this `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Darkman I tried it it does not work. Well I am in windows 10 and use Git bash to run unix commands, so I suppose in order to unzip archives to a specific directory I should use other commands that the ones in 7z script

Comment: Do NOT name your script as same as 7z binaries. Probably something like `7z.sh` would be better.

Comment: I use this command now `unzip -6_dB_fan.zip -d /min6dB` but get an error again  `-d option used more than once (only one exdir allowed)`

Comment: What about this: `unzip -d  './min6db' '-6_db_fan.zip'` or `unzip -d "./min6db" "-6_db_fan.zip"`?` (quotes, hypens).

Comment: nothing worked unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to rewrite it as below and be very careful with spaces:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir ./min6dB
mkdir ./0dB
mkdir ./6dB
unzip "./-6_dB_pump" -d min6dB
unzip "./-6_dB_valve" -d min6dB
unzip 6_dB_valve -d 6dB
unzip 0_dB_valve -d 0dB
unzip 0_dB_pump -d 0dB
unzip 0_dB_fan -d 0dB
```